# DataGrid Cell with text and button

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In a cell of a DataGrid there is a "add" button and then a textblock show quantity.  When the user clicks on the "add" button it adds one to the quantity.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to create the textblock.  Here is my cell;

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="+" Click="addQTYButton_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding qty}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: What's the question? The XAML you provided should work, depending on what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be not to use the Click event and the code-behind.

Use a command instead and in your `ViewModel` change the string the `TextBlock` is bound to when the command is invoked...

If you insist using the event and the code-behind, just name the `TextBlock` and it will be available to you in the event handler to manipulate it any way you like...